# Software/workflow to minify Javascript during development

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a NodeJS application and I am confused on what software/workflow to use to minify my client side Javascript for production. I realize that there are command line tools that can do this, but what does the workflow look like?

In other words, if I have a view that links to main.js during development, do I have to maintain two copies of this file i.e. one that is minified and one that is not?

I cannot imagine having to minify everything and change the script tags to point to the minified files in all of my views. I should also add that I am more concerned with obfuscation in production than I am with the speed of the requests.  Why give potential hackers/thieves more information with all of my comments?

I would appreciate a recommendation on both the software to use and a typical workflow from dev to production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [GulpJS](https://gulpjs.com/) to done some task like minifying. It is easy to use and configure in nodeJS projects.
there are plenty of these task runners like Grunt but if you are a web developer I recommend you to use webpack for this kind of stuff